# Accessing YAML parameters as macros within external LaTeX files

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I'm looking for ways to add variables (or LaTeX macros) to the YAML header or soon after such that they can be used in external `.tex` files that are a part of my (modularised) report.

**My `.rmd` file**

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    includes:
      before_body: some.tex
params:
  cat: "Felix"
  numb: 14
---

# chapter
Oh my \textbf{`r params$cat`}. 
$x = `r 2*params$numb`^2$

<!-- Trying again to get the parameter -->
\input{some.tex}
```

**My `some.tex` file:**

```
`r params\$cat`
```

**Output**

[image]

**Hoped-for output**

I want to be able to somehow pass the variables from the YAML header (or even just below it) to be used by LaTeX so that all important and regularly updated parameters can be viewed and changed in one place.

Comment: In some cases I could use just include the tex file as a child instead of `\include`, but if I wanted to use in in the preamble (in header)...

Comment: May I ask why you are sourcing external LaTeX files? If you want to make an R Markdown document from multiple files, you could look at using **bookdown**: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/books.html

Comment: @MichaelHarper Thanks for pointer (will look into bookdown). It was an effort to keep things (a highly customized report)  modularised and manageable. It would be a bit messy to have all the content of `include>in_header` (> 100 lines of code) in the original markdown document.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are looking for something which perhaps is most in keeping with the R Markdown workflow, you can customise the template which is used to build the LaTeX output and add all the extra LaTeX code directly to this.

**1. Copying Template**

Firstly, we must make a copy of the [template used by R Markdown](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/inst/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex). The following code will create this in your current working directory:

```
file.copy(system.file("rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex",
          package = "rmarkdown"), "template.tex")
```

**2. Adding Variables**

With our copy, we can define our own [pandoc variables](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#using-variables-in-templates) which will be inserted into the output document. This allows us to specify parameters in the YAML section of the document and they will be updated in the output format. It is exactly the same mechanism which allows us to add `title`, `author`, `date` and for them to be added to the output format.

I have added some code to the front matter of the document at [lines 253-255](https://gist.github.com/dr-harper/66d1ec5abb6ccc47f2d9455db53ed6da#file-template-tex-L253). The exact location doesn't matter, but I also tend to put my customisations before the `\begin{document}` argument:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LO, LE]{$params.value$}
\fancyhead[RO, RE]{$yourParam$}
```

**3. Calling Template from R Markdown**

We can reference the custom template to our R Markdown document [as explained here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html#advanced-customization-1). Here is my minimal example:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    template: template.tex
params:
  value: Text
yourParam: "`r Sys.Date()`"
---

`r params$value`
```

The two parameters will be added to the output replacing the `$params.value$` and `$yourParam$`, and result in the output below:

[image]

The example highlights how the YAML parameters don't have to be nested within the `params` argument, as specified in your original question. Having them specified within the parameters mainly has benefits if you want to build a [parameterized report](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports)

> **Note:** the approach of replacing variables using the pandoc notation `$variable$` is only possible for the main template file defined under the `template` option. It won't work for any of the `includes` arguments or any other external LaTeX files. See [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/909) for more details.

Comment: Brilliant. If I am not misunderstanding (?!) then the Note explains it all **you CAN reference Rmd YAML parameters but ONLY in the template**.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I should make this a little clearer. This approach is used extensively by the **rticles** package: https://github.com/rstudio/rticles . Let me know if you have any more queries about my answer :)

Comment: While other answers are show a lot of ingenuity - I think this is how it is intended to be done.

Comment: Using `rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex` in the template argument seems to be different from when no template is stated: package geometry seems not to be loaded automatically anymore + `fig.height` and `fig.height` on chunks seem to be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty :) That sounds like strange behaviour: you should make sure the template you use matches your version of pandoc installed. You can find out this number by running `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()`

Comment: I get: `‘1.19.2.1’`. This is maybe a topic for a new question but do you know  how to access the relevant template if `default-1.19.2.1.tex` is not to be found in `.\library\rmarkdown\rmd\latex`?

Comment: You can see how the **rmarkdown** package selects the relevant template [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/R/pdf_document.R#L109).  Looks like you are good using the original file. Something else must be going on, so maybe best opening another question.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is mysterious, I opened a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52876814/using-a-custom-template-for-rmd-pdf

Answer (score 6):

This comes only half-way. Still no file as header-input...

Maybe this answer will give someone else an idea to build on..

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
params:
  cat: "Felix"
  numb: 14
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhead[CO,CE]{`r params$cat`}
---

# CHAPTER 1
Oh my \textbf{`r params$cat`}. 
$x = `r 2*params$numb`^2$

```{r child = 'some.tex'}
```
````

**screenshot pdf**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure you can code something together using lua-filters.

First come up with your own include-mechanism (since this needs to happen before variable-substitution, so you cannot use latex's `\input`), but e.g. [this filter](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/553#issuecomment-343327058):

```lua
function Para (elem)
  if #elem.content == 1 and elem.content[1].t == "Image" then
    local img = elem.content[1]
    if img.classes[1] == "markdown" then
      local f = io.open(img.src, 'r')
      local blocks = pandoc.read(f:read('*a')).blocks
      f:close()
      return blocks
    end
  end
end
```

Then do the variable substitution with e.g. [this filter](http://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#replacing-placeholders-with-their-metadata-value):

```lua
local vars = {}

function get_vars (meta)
  for k, v in pairs(meta) do
    if v.t == 'MetaInlines' then
      vars["$" .. k .. "$"] = {table.unpack(v)}
    end
  end
end

function replace (el)
  if vars[el.text] then
    return pandoc.Span(vars[el.text])
  else
    return el
  end
end

return {{Meta = get_vars}, {Str = replace}}
```

This should then work like:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    pandoc_args:
      - '--lua-filter=include.lua'
      - '--lua-filter=substitution.lua'
name: Samuel
---

Look, I can include files:

![](include.md){.markdown}
```

And in `include.md`:

```
Look, I can use variables: \$name\$
```

Comment: Nice. I think I will not use this for now but a great reference for others and perhaps my future self.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a TeX or LaTeX macro in the YAML header, and use that in your `some.tex` file.

For example, put this in your main file:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
      includes:
        before_body: some.tex
header-includes:
- \def\thecat{`r params$cat`}
params:
  cat: "Felix"
  numb: 14
---


# chapter
Oh my \textbf{`r params$cat`}. 
$x = `r 2*params$numb`^2$

\input{some.tex}
```

and put this in `some.tex`:

```
\thecat
```

and things will display the way you want.

[image]

Comment: Great option but header-includes is already used to reference an external file in my case.

Comment: You can have multiple lines there.  Just prefix each of them with the hyphen.  See @Wimpel's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me rephrase the question: The goal is to write a parametrized report. This report uses `\input` to embed a TEX file (e.g. `some.tex`). You are looking for a way to access the YAML parameters in  `some.tex`.

One way to do this is to define LaTeX macros according to the YAML parameters, e.g. the YAML parameter `cat: "Felix"` becomes `\newcommand{\cat}{Felix}`. These TEX macros can then be used throughout the document. (In the main file, `r params$cat` would work as well, but as `some.tex` is not being knitted, here only `\cat` works.)

First, the R code is evaluated. It reads all YAML parameters and writes corresponding macros into `myparams.tex`.<sup>1</sup> Via `header-includes` the generated file `myparams.tex` is included in the intermediate TEX file, which is finally being compiled to PDF.

**Main RMD file**:

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes: "\\input{myparams.tex}"
params:
  cat: "Felix"
  numb: 14
---

```{r, include = FALSE}
if (file.exists("myparams.tex")) {
  file.remove("myparams.tex") # CAUTION: this will DELETE any existing file "myparams.tex"
}
for (param in names(params)) {
  cat(sprintf("\\newcommand{\\%s}{%s}\n", param, params[param]), file = "myparams.tex", append = TRUE)
}
```

Oh my \cat. 
$x = 2 \cdot \numb^2$

Or alternatively: Oh my `r params$cat`. 

\input{some.tex}
````

**`some.tex`**:

```
Oh my \cat. % Here, `r params$cat` won't work.
```

**Output**:

> Oh my Felix. `x = 2 · 14²`
>
> Or alternatively: Oh my Felix.
>
> Oh my Felix, again.

**Contents of `myparams.tex`** (dynamically generated):

```
\newcommand{\cat}{Felix}
\newcommand{\numb}{14}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> It might be a good idea to use a unique prefix for all new LaTeX macros to avoid clashes between build-in LaTeX commands and YAML parameters with the same name.

Comment: This might to be what I am looking for. My report is modularised (to keep the main rmd clean), and `some.tex` is specialized fronmatter such as frontpage, table of cotenents and similar which will vary only very slightly between reports. Unfortunately I have less time to review all the solutions thoroughly than I had expected.

Comment: @snoram I updated my answer. Regarding time to review answers: Well, this is the burden of getting too many good answers ;-) (By the way, maybe you cold try to rephrase the question a little bit? At least I found it quite difficult to figure out what you actually need. In fact, this is why I didn't upvote the question yet: it's a good question but – at least to me – not very clear.)

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks so much!