# Using a custom template for Rmd pdf without changing current setup

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I have recently learned that modifying the default (Pandoc?) template for a `Rmd` pdf report [gives access to some neat customisation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52779863/4552295).

So in order to modify the default template I first move it to my working directory using:

```
file.copy(system.file("rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex", package ="rmarkdown"), "template.tex")
```

Next I type up my `Rmd` file:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    template: template.tex
    keep_tex: true
    latex_engine: xelatex
    includes:
      in_header: in_header.tex
    number_sections: true
---

This is a rmd kind of document.
```

Where `in_header.tex` includes only one line

```
\geometry{a4paper, top=38mm, left=45mm, right=45mm}
```

I first just want to run the `Rmd` file with the template as is (expecting no change) but the report fails to compile *if and only if* I include the template - otherwise it runs without an issue.

The error is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.58 \geometry
[...]
```

**Question**

How can I use the template argument to build on an editable template in my working folder without causing any other change to my current setup.

**Info**

```
> R.Version()[["version.string"]]
[1] "R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)"
> packageVersion("rmarkdown")
[1] ‘1.10’
> packageVersion("knitr")
[1] ‘1.20’
```

Comment: Note: The geometry package now being loaded is just one (easily reproducible) example of an upset to my current order of things when I add the template.

Comment: Did you get a chance to view this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139139/adding-headers-and-footers-using-pandoc

Comment: @Naveen Thanks, but I can't see the connection. I would like to add a template that doesn't affect the current setup at all - because I am very far into building my report already.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you are already driving this from R, you may as well use the (excellent) example set up by the [rticles](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rticles) package which provides a larged number of LaTeX customizations for (academic) papers.

And you can then run with that them. For example, over the last two years I added these packages:

- [tint](https://cran.r-project.org/package=tint) for a modern 'Tufte-alike' writeup
- [pinp](https://cran.r-project.org/package=pinp) for very nice two-column pdf vignettes
- [link](https://cran.r-project.org/package=linl) for LaTeX letters and some extra
- [binb](https://cran.r-project.org/package=binb) for variants of beaner packages

This allows you to

- set a custom `template.tex`
- include whichever LaTeX class files / style files you need
- programmatically set options

I find this preferable to copying stanzas around which I did previously (eg for slides).

Comment: I guess that is **very** useful if I have there is a predefined style that I am following. But I am kind of developing my own style. The current setup *does allow* me to set a custom `template.tex` but a few things change from the previous setup when I add `template: template.tex` (not limited to the geometry package).

Comment: Yes, and those you could then wrap up in your package to available for the project of yours.  Been there, done that ....

Comment: Didn't get the new answers I was hoping for with the bounty, so I'll leave the bonus here at the most upvoted answer.

Answer (score 5):

The `rmarkdown::pdf_output` function seems to do a few things differently when the `default` template is used. For example, it sets the variable `graphics=yes`. I suspect that it also sets `geometry`, but I have not seen where it does that. Anyway, if you want to use a custom template based on the default template you are "fighting" with this block from the template:

```
$if(geometry)$
\usepackage[$for(geometry)$$geometry$$sep$,$endfor$]{geometry}
$endif$
```

The `geometry` package is only loaded, when the geometry header is defined. One simple solution to your problem is to move the geometry definition from the header include to the YAML header:

```
---
geometry:
  - a4paper
  - top=38mm
  - left=45mm
  - right=45mm
output:
  pdf_document:
    template: template.tex
    keep_tex: true
    latex_engine: xelatex
    includes:
      in_header: in_header.tex
    number_sections: true
---

This is a rmd kind of document.
```

With this you can remove `\geometry{...}` from  `in_header.tex`.

Comment: I was hoping that it would not do *a few things differently*. I wonder if there is a list somwhere of what it is that it does differently.

Comment: @snoram I know of no such list. I used the source of the function and compared the `.tex` files produced w/ and w/o the custom template.