# Create Memo in R Markdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown, memo, cls

I am trying to create the following memo format in R Mardown:
https://texblog.org/2012/03/07/writing-a-memo-in-latex/

```
---
csl: texMemo.csl

\memoto{someone} 
output: pdf_document
---
```

I'm not sure where to put the text, whether it does in the YAML header or the body of the R Markdown. Also the Latex code does not work in the header. I'd imagine there is an easy solution but I cannot find answers. Thanks.

Comment: A custom template would be the way to go. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52876814/using-a-custom-template-for-rmd-pdf-without-changing-current-setup for some examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference between `csl` and `cls`. A `.cls` file is a document class definition file, whereas `.csl` files define citation styles.

**1. Make new document class known to TeX**

Following your link we get our hands on a class definition file. Usually, you would place the file in your local texmf directory tree (kind of installing it if you will) and can then create tex documents using `\documentclass{texMemo}`. Check [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10498/installing-a-class) thread on installing class definitions.

Alternatively you can simply place the `.cls` file in the same directory as your RMarkdown document.

**2. Create a new template**

Afterwards you can set the YAML option `dcoumentclass: texMemo` but you run into conflicts with the default pdf template. So what you would have to do then is to also create a pandoc template (lets call it `template.tex`) and include it via the YAML option `template: template.tex`. A basic template can be

```
\documentclass{texMemo}

\usepackage{graphicx} % needed for the logo

\memoto{$to$}
\memofrom{$from$}
\memosubject{$title$}
\memodate{$date$}
\logo{$logo$}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

$body$ % will be replaced by the content of your rmd document

\end{document}
```

Place it in the same directory as well.

**3. Create the RMD**

Finally you can create your rmarkdown document. Here is an example:

```
---
title: "Dinner"
to: Ralf
from: Martin
date: "`r Sys.time()`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    template: template.tex
logo: "\\includegraphics[width=.25\\textwidth]{unnamed.png}"
---

Let us have dinner next week.
```

[image]

---

*Sidenote:*

The product of such a process could be a package providing your own output format. I had some spare time and created such a package. You can install it using

```
devtools::install_github("martinschmelzer/rmemo")
```

Then you can choose the "Memorandum" template from File -> New -> RMarkdown. A logo is added using the YAML option `logo: mylogo.png`. Almost all of the other YAML options documented for the default latex template work as well. So does `geometry` in case you want to alter the document margins.

I took the code from Rob Oak (creator of the document class texMemo) and embetted it directly in a default latex template. If you want to make changes/imrpovements, feel free to open pull requests.

Comment: That's great! Very nice memo.